# How to move WooCommerce my-account inside wp-admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, account

I am trying to move "my-account" page into wp-admin.

Here is my source code :

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'create_etrade_admin_menu' );

function create_etrade_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'My Auctions', 'Auctions', 'manage_options', 'etrade-auction-admin-page.php', 'etrade_auction_admin_page', 'dashicons-email', 6  );
}

function etrade_auction_admin_page(){
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Auctions and Bids</h1>

       <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); ?>

    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working.

My question is: Is it possible to use "`do_shortcode()`" inside function for wp-admin area?

Or is there any other option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary remarks:**

- Customer user role is not allowed to go in admin area.
- My account is a frontend page. It's based on woocommerce templates that are only used for front end purpose and made for it.
- `'manage_options'` capability is only for Administrator user role (used in `create_etrade_admin_menu()` function).

**Shortcodes for backend?**

- **Shortcodes are used normally for front end purposes, but not for backend.** However you can call the associated functions in backend (but mostly will not work).

**My account page on Back end?**

You will need to build your project from scratch, may be using some code of [WooCommerce templates](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)…

*Building a backend page:*

*1. A backend menu access with `add_menu_page()` function.*
*2. The submenu calling your page with `add_submenu_page()` function (optional)*. 
*3. The page is build with a function which name will be called back by `add_menu_page()` (and `add_submenu_page()`)…*

Reference:

- [add_menu_page function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)
- [add_submenu_page function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)